# MySQL 5.7 vs. 8.0 Regression Performance on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

I am testing the performance of MySQL 5.7.42 vs. MySQL 8.0.33 on Ubuntu 22.04 (amd64). Each of the test is using their own AWS EC2 instance (t2.2xlarge which has 8 core/32 GB). I ran a simple sysbench (1.0.20 version) test like this:

```
sysbench oltp_read_write --table-size=100000 ... prepare
sysbench oltp_read_write --table-size=100000 --threads=4 --max-requests=0 --time=30 ... run
```

|  | MySQL 5.7.42 | MySQL 8.0.33 (stock) | MySQL 8.0.33 (config change) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| transactions/sec | 483.60 / sec | 306.87 / sec | 389.31 / sec |
| queries/sec | 9671.90 / sec | 6137.38 / sec | 7786.80 / sec |

Just to clarify on the 2 columns on MySQL 8.0.33, the (stock) means there is no configuration change, while the (config change) means I added the "skip-log-bin" in my.cnf.

Based on the result, MySQL 8.0 seems to be slower than 5.7. I am not sure why this is the case. Has anyone seen something similar to this?

Also, I wonder if it is related to these bugs. [MySQL Bug 108430](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=108430) or [MySQL Bug 93734](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93734) ?

By the way, I can give more details (eg. commands that I used, full output of Sysbench, etc.) that I used if that helps.

Comment: Is it slower for _your_ transactions and queries?  How many xacts/sec and qps does your app run?  How much RAM on the box?  Did you also test MariaDB?

Comment: Yes, when we ran our local tests wrt to the app, it is slower. We ran 4,800 queries. The average query time for 5.7 is 0.56 ms while 8.0 is 1.43 ms. The total duration time for 5.7 is 2,666 ms while 8.0 is 6,814 ms. Also, I tested this Sysbench test and our local app test on MariaDB 10.6.4 and it ran as fast as 5.7.

I am hesitant to switch to MariaDB for local testing because our Production will eventually run Aurora-MySQL 3.03.1 which is equivalent to MySQL 8.0.26.

Comment: Did you happen to have the slowlog turned on (with low value of `long_query_time`) during those tests?  I am fishing for whether only one query became a lot slower -- In this case, let's focus on that query.  We may find a regression in 8.0 and/or a setting that can trick 8.0 into running that query as fast as 5.7.

Comment: Aurora is not completely equivalent to 8.0.  The Query cache is available on Aurora; did you have it turned on?  The underlying disk architecture is quite different.  Etc.

Comment: The slow query log was turned on and the 8.0 was generally slow by a few milliseconds. There wasn’t a query that really regressed. The testing was all done in vanilla MySQL.

Comment: In your personal opinion, would you do your local testing in MariaDB but then use Aurora-MySQL for prod? Currently, we do our local testing with vanilla MySQL and use Aurora-MySQL in prod. We don’t use any specific MariaDB advance features so in theory we could use it for local testing.

Comment: MySQL's and MariaDB's Optimizers diverged years ago.  Usually you can't tell the difference, but occasionally there is a big diff.  One will run a query much faster than the other.  Even within either product, there are Optimization improvements _and sometimes regressions_.  I don't want to chase the benchmark, but I will chase issues with _your_ queries.